# Can't run and debug groovy tests under intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I try to embed groovy test to java project.
I start with spock examples - https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example

Examples is compile and execute by running maven goal test but if i try to run test under intellij idea (ctrl+F10 under test method) it failure with classpath error.

> Error running HelloSpockSpec.length of Spock's and his friends' names:
>   Class 'HelloSpockSpec' not found in module 'spock-example'

I try to apply advices from [IntelliJ + Groovy + Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389849/intellij-groovy-spock) but it didn't help.

Comment: Is the folder marked as test sources?

Comment: You are right! I miss to do it. Thank you. If you right answer i will vote and mark it as complete.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't forget to mark the folder as "Test Sources" in IntelliJ

Then it should work as expected :-)

Comment: Just for in case... Right click on `test/groovy` folder -> `Mark Directory as` -> `Test sources root`

Answer (score 5):

Intellij can automatically add the groovy source as a source directory based on your pom. Add build-helper-maven-plugin config to your maven pom under `plugins` specifying `${basedir}/src/test/groovy` as a source dir:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-groovy-test-source</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/test/groovy</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```